# Why does mathdesign result in a huge 'cases' environment brace in Tufte documents?

Tags: amsmath, tufte, cases, mathdesign

I'm getting strange results when I use the `cases` environment in Tufte-LaTeX documents with the `mathdesign` package. Instead of

[image]

I get

[image]

Is there something I can do to get rid of that huge brace?

---

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{mathtools}

%The following appears to be the source of my problems; removing this line produces an acceptable result
\RequirePackage[bitstream-charter,expert,euro]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\[
a(1,j)=\begin{cases}
r^{j-1} & ;j\le n\\
f\cdot r^{j-(n+1)} & ;j>n
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The fix is simply to set `\delimiterfactor=912`. That seems to be the largest value that solves the problem. Tufte-LaTeX must set it to something larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big brace you get is built from smaller pieces and that's the minimum size as the following minimal document shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\def\test#1{$\left\{\rule{0pt}{#1pt}(#1\textrm{pt})\right.$ }

\noindent\test{6}
\test{8}
\test{10}
\test{12}
\test{14}
\test{16}
\test{18}
\test{20}
\test{22}
\test{24}
\test{26}
\test{28}
\test{30}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Up to the 18pt case the brace is a unique glyph. Beyond that point TeX must build the brace from smaller pieces and in the case of the Charter math fonts provided by `mathdesign` this has an unfortunate gap.

There's a fundamental difference in behaviour between `tufte-book` and `article`: the former sets the normal baselineskip to 14pt instead of the 12pt of the `article` class. So, with `tufte-book`, the array that contains the two cases is

```
\vbox(28.55986+5.04002)x83.62628
```

while with `article` it is

```
\vbox(24.47987+4.32002)x80.47983
```

So it's a bit wider both horizontally and vertically. Indeed, if you try

```
\[
a(1,j)=\begin{cases}
r^{j-1} & ;j\le n\\[4.8pt]
f\cdot r^{j-(n+1)} & ;j>n
\end{cases}
\]
```

with the `article` class, you'll see the same behavior as with `tufte-book`.

Comment: How do I avoid tipping over that 18-20 pt gap in the example above?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius In that particular case, inputting `r^{\smash{j-1}}` avoids jumping to the next size.

Comment: Is there a general way to override LaTeX's judgment on the side of brace that should be used? And (perhaps this is a meta equation) is there a way to confirm that this is a logged bug, or get some sense of when it's likely to be fixed?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You should look at `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` in the TeXbook or TeX by Topic. But I'm afraid that this is a limitation of the *specific* font, not of TeX.

Comment: Understood: my question was whether I could prevent TeX's (correct) logic (that a 20pt brace is appropriate) from kicking in an resulting in the font's too-large one. For example an 18pt brace would be better in this case (for this font).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You can't, in general. You might enlarge the value of `\delimitershortfall` or reducing `\delimitershortfall`, which works for the particular case, but might give bad results for a bigger brace. The problem is precisely the gap: try the same input with the Computer Modern fonts and you won't see it.

Comment: Would it also make sense to insert a space between the two cases? Is there a good way to do that within a `cases` environment?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's an option: `\\[<dimen>]` works also in `cases`.

Comment: Why doesn't this problem happen in other document classes? The problem doesn't occur if I replace `tuft-handout` with `article` in my MWE?

Comment: Using `r^{\smash{j-1}}` has no effect in my MWE.