# refcheck and \nameref not getting along

Tags: hyperref, refcheck

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[norefs]{refcheck}
\begin{document}
As we will see later (see \nameref{ans}), the answer is 42.
\section{The answer}\label{ans}
This simplifies to 42.
\end{document}
```

This typesets properly, but I get a warning that ans is never referenced.  How can I get refcheck to realize that it was?

Comment: `refcheck` manual says that it should be loaded after `hyperref`, but using it the other way round will make the error message to vanish

Comment: Unfortunately, the manual is right.  Loading it the other way is equivalent to not loading refcheck at all, so it's not too surprising the error vanishes :)

Comment: `refcheck` does a lot of redefinitions with the internal commands `\ref` etc. Perhaps this can be replicated for `\nameref` as well

Comment: See my updated answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning, this does not work for `\nameref*` so far...

`refcheck` redefines the usual `\...ref` commands like `\ref`, `\pageref` and `\biblabel` etc., and hooks into those commands, storing the argument to a list (of used label names) but it does not provide a similar approach for `\nameref`.

I assume, that `\cref` etc. from `cleveref` will fail as well then.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[norefs]{refcheck}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\@@nameref@@\nameref
\expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\expandafter
{\csname relax\string\nameref\endcsname}[1]{\@@nameref@@{#1}\wrtusdrf{#1}}%
\expandafter\let\expandafter\nameref\csname relax\string\nameref\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
As we will see later (see \nameref{ans}), the answer is 42.
\section{The answer}\label{ans}
This simplifies to 42.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what sorcery this is, but it certainly seems to work.  I don't need the star variants anyway.  I have no clue how you did that so fast.  I sometimes suspect some of you people know the code for every package on ctan or something.  Anyway, thank you!!

Comment: @Mark: Usually we have CTAN almost completely on our disks, so it's 'easy' to look into the code ;-)

Comment: Obviously you have it on disk, but no mere mortal could read and understand an entire package like refcheck that fast, surely?

Comment: @Mark: I had just a suspicion that `refcheck` would use a hooking approach for `\label` and `\ref....` -- the rest was copying and adapting to `\nameref` ;-)

Comment: Fair enough... I'm still going to call it sorcery :)

Comment: Do you suppose it makes sense to report this as a bug/feature request to the refcheck maintainer?

Comment: @Mark: Let's call it a missing feature :D (It's no bug really -- the maintainer(s) just forgot to take care about `\nameref`)

Comment: So, do you think it makes sense to ask for this feature?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I think so. The maintainer's mail address can be found on CTAN

Comment: Yep, you're right, found it.  Emailing now.

Comment: @Mark: That's fine. Please keep me informed, by chance!

Comment: No response so far.

Comment: @Mark: Well, I did not expect the Spanish Inquisition --, I mean, a quick response ;-)

Comment: @Mark: Any news?

Comment: And answer came there none :(

Comment: @Mark: Looks like the author abandoned the maintenance of the package.

Comment: Probably.  Unless there's some other explanation we're missing.

Comment: @Mark: Unless the author isn't on an expedition to the two summits of Mount Kilimanjaro (;-)) and will not return before the next Star Wars movies is released, we have to wait some time and if there's no reaction, the `take-over-authorship-and-rule-the-world` machinery starts  (however, I've no idea how to trigger this. Perhaps I've to ask the folks of CTAN about this)

Comment: Shouldn't at least someone else send an email first, to make sure it's not just an allergic reaction to my email or something? :)

Comment: @Mark: Define 'someone'. John Doe?

Comment: Someone from CTAN?

Comment: @Mark: I think that's the usual way to achieve this. I can ask Joseph Wright also -- he has taken over maintenance for some packages, I think he knows the procedure. Besides all of this: the CTAN folks sometimes have another mail address of the authors to contact them, which differs from the official package 'mail address'.

Comment: @Mark: And it will certainly not me who takes the maintenance. In this case, Heiko Oberdiek (maintainer of `hyperref`) should do the job (he will curse me for this proposition ;-)) and thereby use his knowledge, of course

Comment: Oh dear.  Look what I've started.  I didn't mean to start curses flying! ;)

Comment: @Mark: See the very related question (about the maintenance issue) here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188430/publishing-a-package-update-on-ctan